# Inserting link to help page

Tags: documentation, hyperlink

How do I insert a link to a particular help page in Mathematica? Insert > Hyperlink... does not seem to offer this option. In particular, I am trying to link to guide/MatrixDecompositions.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with

```
Hyperlink[
  "Matrix Decompositions", 
  "paclet:guide/MatrixDecompositions", 
  Appearance -> "Frameless", 
  BaseStyle -> {"Text"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

paclet:guide/MatrixDecompositions

in the Destination notebook: | Other notebook or URL:

section of the Insert->Hyperlink dialog.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks. Importantly, it seems to be platform-independent, whereas hard links to files in Documentation don't work across mac, linux, windows.